# SQL using MAX and COUNT

Tags: sql, select, count, max

I need to select all things with the maximum number of rows.

I am using this:

```
SELECT TMP.S, MAX(TMP.my_count)
FROM (
  SELECT T1.something S, COUNT(*) my_count
  FROM table T1, table2 T2
  WHERE T1.value = T2.value
  GROUP BY T1.something) TMP
GROUP BY TMP.S
```

However this ends up with the same result as only this:

```
SELECT T1.something, COUNT(*) my_count
FROM table T1, table2 T2
WHERE T1.value = T2.value
GROUP BY T1.something
```

I could use `ORDER BY my_count DESC` with `ROWNUM = 1`, but that does not solve my problem, cause I need to choose all maximums if they have the same values.

Comment: It seems T is an alias for no table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Max` in your `Where` condition:

```
SELECT TMP.S, TMP.my_count
FROM (
      SELECT T1.something S, COUNT(*) my_count
      FROM table T1, table2 T2
      WHERE T1.value = T2.value
      GROUP BY T1.something 
      ) TMP
Where 
TMP.my_count = (select max(count(*)) from table1 T3 group by t3.something)
```